# Find all decompositions in two factors of a number

Tags: python, algorithm, combinations

For a given `N`, I am trying to find every positive integers `a` and `b` such that `N = a*b`.

I start decomposing into prime factors using [`sympy.ntheory.factorint`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/ntheory.html), it gives me a dict factor -> exponent.

I have this code already, but I don't want to get duplicates (`a` and `b` play the same role):

```py
import itertools

from sympy.ntheory import factorint


def find_decompositions(n):
    prime_factors = factorint(n)
    cut_points = {f: [i for i in range(1+e)] for f, e in prime_factors.items()}
    cuts = itertools.product(*cut_points.values())
    decompositions = [((a := np.prod([f**e for f, e in zip(prime_factors, cut)])), n//a) for cut in cuts]
    return decompositions
```

Example:

```py
In [235]: find_decompositions(12)
Out[235]: [(1, 12), (3, 4), (2, 6), (6, 2), (4, 3), (12, 1)]
```

What I would like to get instead:

```py
Out[235]: [(1, 12), (3, 4), (2, 6)]
```

I tried to reduce halve the range in `cut_points` with range extends such as `e//2`, `1 + e//2`, `(1+e)//2`, `1 + (1+e)//2`. None of it ended up working.

A simple solution is obviously to compute the same and return:

```py
decompositions[:(len(decompositions)+1)//2]
```

but I am looking for an eventual solution that reduces the number of computations instead.

Comment: Factorization "sympy.ntheory.factorint" is the expensive operation in your algorithm. After that everything else can be assumed as 'cheap'. (alt least for numbers with more than one 'large' prime factor)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using module `sympy`, which already has [a `divisors` function](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/ntheory.html#sympy.ntheory.factor_.divisors):

```py
from sympy import divisors

print(divisors(12))
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 12]

def find_decompositions(n):
    divs = divisors(n)
    half = (len(divs) + 1) // 2  # +1 because perfect squares have odd number of divisors
    return list(zip(divs[:half], divs[::-1]))

print(find_decompositions(12))
# [(1, 12), (2, 6), (3, 4)]

print(find_decompositions(100))
# [(1, 100), (2, 50), (4, 25), (5, 20), (10, 10)]
```

Comment: Nice! I don't know much about sympy as I am just using for the first time. Thanks!

Comment: Need a fix though for being accepted: `half = (len(divs)+1)//2` (`find_decompositions(100)` misses `(10, 10)` for example)

Comment: @NickSkywalker Indeed! Fixed

Answer (score 2):

You can take advantage of the fact that the way you generate `cuts` means every `cut` at position `i` has a complement at position `-i`. You need a little extra logic in case `n` is a square number

```
def find_decompositions_paired(n):
    prime_factors = factorint(n)
    primes = np.array(list(prime_factors.keys()))
    prime_exponents = np.array(list(prime_factors.values()))
    cut_points = [range(1+e) for e in prime_factors.values()]

    cuts = [c for c in itertools.product(*cut_points)]
    decompositions = [
        (a, b) for a, b in zip(cuts[:len(cuts)//2], cuts[::-1])
    ]
    # if n is a square there's going to be an orphan
    if len(cuts) % 2:
        decompositions.append((cuts[len(cuts)//2], cuts[len(cuts)//2]))

    # calculate the value of the primes from the factors
    decompositions = [
        (np.power(primes, d[0]).prod(), np.power(primes,d[1]).prod())
        for d in decompositions
    ]
    return decompositions
```

Testing with 36 gives the correct decomposition

```
In [156]: find_decompositions_paired(36)
[((0, 0), (2, 2)), ((0, 1), (2, 1)), ((0, 2), (2, 0)), ((1, 0), (1, 2)), ((1, 1), (1, 1))]
Out[156]: [(1, 36), (3, 12), (9, 4), (2, 18), (6, 6)]
```

There's about a factor of 1/3 speedup

```
In [177]: %timeit find_decompositions(np.prod(range(1,20))) 
474 ms ± 12.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [178]: %timeit find_decompositions_paired(np.prod(range(1,20)))
303 ms ± 7.47 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

For completeness we can see how the native `sympy` `divisors` function
fares. (as per Stef's answer).

```
def find_decompositions_sympy(n):
    div = divisors(n)
    half = len(div) // 2 + 1
    return [(div[i], div[-i-1]) for i in range(half)]
```

Unsurprisingly it fares far far better.

```
In [179]: %timeit find_decompositions_sympy(np.prod(range(1,20)))
13.1 ms ± 443 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: huh... stupidity on my part. thanks for catching it. Fixing up the answer now

Comment: Note that there is also `math.prod` from the standard python library, which seems more appropriate for a `range`, and which returns a python integer rather than an `np.int64`.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. Using the `divisors` function seems like the best approach though.

Answer (score 0):

Unless your N is really large, you could probably use a simple list comprehension that iterates up to the square root of N and selects divisors and their counterpart:

```
def factorPairs(N):
    return [ (f,N//f) for f in range(1,int(N**0.5)+1) if N%f == 0 ]

print(factorPairs(12))
[(1, 12), (2, 6), (3, 4)]

print(factorPairs(36))
[(1, 36), (2, 18), (3, 12), (4, 9), (6, 6)]
```

Comment: I suggest `from math import isqrt` and then `1 + isqrt(N-1)` instead of `int(N**0.5)+1`